# Different usage between: getElementsBy..(..), not getElementBy

Tags: javascript, html

In Javascript, we have `getElementById`,`getElementsByTagName`. I want to understand is there something underneath the hood about using getElement**s**ByTagName, rather than just `getElementByTagName`. Because it sometimes confuse me a little bit to write the code.

Comment: Multiple elements can have the same tagname, but only on element can have a unique id.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName read the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per standards, `id` should be used for **one** and **only one** element.
Therefore there is `getElementById` and not `getElementsById`.

On the other hand, multiple elements can have same `tag`. So, we have `getElementsByTag`. Similarly, `getElementsByClassName`.